# Argumentation advice on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Can I ask on sus.se for

1. factual information (such as wattage/flight)
2. argumentation patterns (such as diverting the "everyone is flying, not just me" strawman argument)
3. lead-ups to 2) which try to minimize their feeling about being "railroaded" to a topic. It is a good friend after all, and I value them as a being, but want to educate.

If I am partially offtopic, thats perfectly agreeable, just tell me so. It has not been specified in the help, this is why I ask.

**Why I ask:**

I have a friend who is aware about sustainability as such, but fails to quantify the footstep his actions are producing. I'd like to give an example of what i mean:

We are both schooled in the means of electronic engineering. He spends alot of time researching components (for a personal project) which do use 0.1 instead of 1 watts of energy. Then he goes off to the airport, for a weekend journey of a sub-1000km journey within europe (easily done via train) and back. I understand that we need low-wattage components in mass use, but I see him getting the neccesities upside-down.

I understand this is all a bit short, I shall refine this Q when sub-questions arise.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can certainly ask about data ("factual information") concerning the amount of energy per person for a (full) flight of a certain distance.

I don't think we can tell you how to convince your friend of your ideas ("argumentation patterns").